# Setup Asp.Net Core app to launch Vue SPA with webpack and HMR

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

I'm trying to set up a new application using ASP.NET Core 3.0 and Vue. I've been struggling to set it up properly so that the backend and frontend servers are correctly integrated, with proper routing and working HMR. I do have it working now, but I can't tell if this is the correct way do this, and there are some pieces that I don't feel are working as well as they can.

My current setup:

Webpack is configured to output files into `wwwroot`. I also have HMR and 
[WriteFilePlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-file-webpack-plugin) enabled when running [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html):

```
 mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // write files to fs instead of memory
    // so that the server can access and serve index.html
    new WriteFilePlugin(),
  ],
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true,
    },
    port: 9001,
  },
```

In `Startup.cs`:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
          .....
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot";
            });
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
       {
           app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                    {
                        // run the dev server 
                        endpoints.MapToVueCliProxy("{*path}", new SpaOptions { SourcePath = "ClientApp" },
                            npmScript: "serve", regex: "Compiled successfully");
                    }
                }
                // serve index.html file when no api endpoints are matched
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
       }
```

My problems with this setup:

- Typically, HMR builds files in memory, but I have it set up here to write the new files to the file system so that the backend server can access and serve the `index.html`. This works, but now I have tons of bloat being written to my file system. Is there a way to use the in-memory HMR in conjunction with the ASP.NET server?
- The proxying isn't always reliable; I often get errors in the console that it can't connect to the server. Additionally, `index.html` sometimes gets cached and I have to do a hard reload. Can this be made more reliable somehow?

Comment: I have not used the .net core stuff that you're using, that looks like it's specially designed for the job. But my workflow for this, which also works, is to have express sitting in front of your apis and your spa, reverse proxying spa requests to the webpack dev server. You need to also hand over the websocket requests. I can post my script if you're interested.

Comment: @stellr42 - Did you figure this out? I have same issue with .Net core 3.1.